# GNUstep NSString.m file

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

I'm using GNUstep to begin with learning Objective-C.
I could find the header files for all, but don't know where to find its implementation files.
I was thinking, with that I can understand the whole programming style and many more.

I am working without mac , so if some body knows about any good tutorials , that i can use to identify structure of every Classes.

For instance, i have to parse an xml file, just to learn,
but don't know where to start.
Without IDE its hard to find out the sequence, and I don't have got access to any tutorials that best explains this, ( all that i get is in accordance with i-Phone and Cocoa. )

I'm concentrating on console programs, so that I can be thorough with the syntax and language.

Pls help me.

Answer (score 4):

http://gnustep.org/ is the best resource for GNUstep related information, including source and documentation.

Comment: But tellme where i can see NSString.m in my system. actually i am asking, we include *.m file in our gcc compilation and import *.h files from those *.m files. But i dont see including NSString.m and other *.m file qhile we compile...may be this is a problem of mine, in the concept that i understand.

Comment: @Sumit: There are no implementation files on your system. It's already been compiled into the Base library. You have to get the source to look at...well, the source.

Comment: see, xml part and many others are incomplete...
http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php?title=NSXMLParser&action=edit

http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/Foundation

Answer (score 0):

**GNUStep** has some tutorials and definitely the source code available.

You will find that there are small bits and pieces where `Cocoa` has moved on so `GNUStep` will not recognize new methods and things like properties or any new objective-2.0 stuff and so on.

Comment: But tellme where i can see NSString.m in my system. actually i am asking, we include *.m file in our gcc compilation and import *.h files from those *.m files. But i dont see including NSString.m and other *.m file qhile we compile...may be this is a problem of mine, in the concept that i understand.

Comment: .m files get compiled into objects and are distributed as frameworks (on Mac) after compiling you would link against framework that already provides compiled object files

Comment: on mac you would see in the linking process something like `-framework Foundation` when your code is using Foundation classes

Comment: Meaning, you will not usually see the .m files like NSString.m (if one exists) unless you download the source code for Foundation classes and look inside

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you have the source installed, you can find NSString.m here

/path_to_my_src/gnustep/modules/core/base/Source/NSString.m